# Force Callback to reload file

Tags: php, jquery, image, crop, image-uploading

I'm using a php and jQuery tool to upload and crop pictures. It works well. But i'd like to have a preview after i uploaded and croped the pictures. I got the preview, but it's the pictures befor the crop. I guess it takes the picture from any cache. When i check out the real file on the server it is croped.

Is there any idea how i can force the following function to really get the file new from the server?

That is the Code, where i put the url back to the div in the form for the preview.

```
    new ImgSelect( $('#imgselect_container'), {
cropComplete: function(image) {
    $('.avatar').html('<img src="scripts/imgSelect/files/' + image.name + '">');
        }
    });
```

Comment: If this is actually caused by cache append a cache busting string to the url, like a timestamp. `+ image.name + '?t='+ timestamp +`

Comment: Good idear, but i got this JavaScript Error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: timestamp is not defined`

Comment: You need to define that your self - I left it as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force the image to be downloaded again you can append a timestamp in the  querystring. Try this:

```
$('.avatar').html('<img src="scripts/imgSelect/files/' + image.name + '?t=' + +new Date + '">');
```

You could also amend the cache settings of your server.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I think there is a + to much befor new Date, i dropped that, but still not working, same issue, the uncropped pictures will be loaded.

Comment: @Fabrizio no, the `+` before `new Date()` is needed. It converts the date to a number.

Comment: :D Sorry, i did it now with the + and it gave my a url like ...?t=14.... so it lookes correctly, but it is still the uncropped picture.

Comment: _“so it lookes correctly, but it is still the uncropped picture”_ – well then it is probably not an actual caching issue, but rather a _timing_ issue – because the image is not finished processing on the server side already.

Comment: @CBroe :p good Point, any idea how to make a delay or a Tipp where to Start again with the debugging?

Comment: Well you could try with a timeout and _hope_ that processing is done by then … or check the documentation of the tool you are using to see if it explicitly provides something to handle that use case.

Comment: oh, i tried it now again and it works. I bet i'm maybe not reloaded the page properly or some other cache problem. But it works! Thank you very much +1